# Disable mouse middle click using jquery not support in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, onclick

I have try to disable mouse middle click on link.following code

```
$(selector).on('click', function(e) { 
   if(e.which == 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

this works fine in chrome.but not work in Firefox.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "<selector>", function (ev) {
    if (ev.which == 2) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This worked for me. Please try this. Hope it helps!!